# $\{a_n\}$ is defined by $a_1=\sqrt{7}$ and $a_{(n+1)}=\sqrt{7 a_n}$ for all $n \geq 1.$ Prove that $7\geq a_n$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, inequality

$\{a_n\}$ is defined by $a_1=\sqrt{7}$ and $a_{(n+1)}=\sqrt{7 a_n},$ for all $n \geq 1.$ Prove that $7\geq a_n.$

This is what I did :

I proved using induction that this series is increasing therefore $a_n<a_{n+1}$.

so I managed to reach to this inequailty :

$$a_n < \sqrt{7 a_n}$$

I think I could make this all in square, therefore :

$$a_n^2<7 a_n \\ a_n(a_n-7)<0$$

Now I don't understand how using the inequailty I should show that $7\geq a_n$

Any ideas?

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: Just show directly that if $a_n \geq 7$, then $a_{n+1} = \sqrt{7 a_n} \geq 7$.

Comment: @anomaly Is it possible to use the method with the inequality instand induction?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that.

Comment: @anomaly I'll try to be more clear, I'd want to proof this without using induction, is it possible to proof this algebraic instand?

Comment: Well, the sequence is defined inductively, so you're probably going to have to use induction somewwhere.

Comment: You have $a_n>a_{n-1}>...a_1>0$ so $a_n-7$ must be negative for the product to be negative. Hence...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint** :
by induction (without knowing that $a_n$ is increasing):

- $a_1\leq 7$
- if $a_n\leq 7$ then $a_{n+1}\leq \sqrt{7a_n}\leq 7$

If you proved that it's increasing than $a_{n+1}\leq a_n$ gives you $a_n(a_n-7)\leq 0$ and we know $a_n$ is positive so $a_n-7\leq 0$ hence $a_n\leq 7$ ( your method is fine).

Comment: Can you explain why $a_n(a_n-7) \leq 0 \implies a_n \leq 7$?

Comment: @JaVaPG I edited the answer

Answer (score 1):

The function $f(x)=\sqrt{7x}$ has a fixed point at $7$ as shown in the picture. Since $a_1 = f(1)$ and $a_2 = f(f(1))$ and so on, we actually have $a_n \uparrow 7$. In fact, starting with any $0 < a_1 < 7$, we always have $a_n \uparrow 7$.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like induction, then you can take logarithm and get $\log_7a_{n+1}=\frac{1}{2}[1+\log_7(a_n)]$. Hence, $\log_7a_{n+1}-1=\frac{1}{2}[\log_7a_n-1]$. We have $\log_7a_n-1=-\frac{1}{2^n}<0$.

Comment: How is $-1/2^n > 0$?

Comment: Sorry, that's a typo.